# Is there an R function that automatically makes columns/variable names in a dataframe nice?

Tags: r

I believe I have seen this but I can't remember what it is called.

```
names <- colnames(dataframe)

foo_Bar
data_Tape
```

would become

```
foo.bar
data.tape
```

Comment: `tolower(make.names("foo_Bar", allow_ = F))`?

Comment: OR `gsub("_", ".", colnames(dataframe), fixed = TRUE)`